# How do I influence the width of Perl IPC::Open3 output?

Tags: perl, terminal, ipcopen3

I have the following Perl code and would like it to display exactly as invoking `/bin/ls` in the terminal would display. For example on a terminal sized to 100 columns, it would print up to 100 characters worth of output before inserting a newline. Instead this code prints 1 file per line of output. I feel like it involves assigning some terminal settings to the `IO::Pty` instance, but I've tried variations of that without luck.

**UPDATE:** I replaced the `<$READER>` with a call to `sysread` hoping the original code might just have a buffering issue, but the output received from `sysread` is still one file per line.

**UPDATE:** I added code showing my attempt at changing the IO::Pty's size via the `clone_winsize_from` method. This didn't result in the output being any different.

**UPDATE:** As best I can tell (from reading IPC::open3 code for version 1.12) it seems you cannot pass a variable of type IO::Handle without `open3` creating a pipe rather than `dup`'ing the filehandle. This means `isatty` doesn't return a true value when `ls` invokes it and `ls` then forces itself into "one file per line" mode.

I think I just need to do a fork/exec and handle the I/O redirection myself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use IPC::Open3;
use IO::Pty;
use strict;

my $READER = IO::Pty->new();
$READER->slave->clone_winsize_from(\*STDIN);

my $pid = open3(undef, $READER, undef, "/bin/ls");

while(my $line = <$READER>)
{
    print $line;
}
waitpid($pid, 0) or die "Error waiting for pid: $!\n";

$READER->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `$READER` is getting overwritten with a pipe created by `open3`, which can be avoided by changing

```
my $READER = ...;
my $pid = open3(undef, $READER, undef, "/bin/ls");
```

to

```
local *READER = ...;
my $pid = open3(undef, '>&READER', undef, "/bin/ls");
```

See the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3).

Comment: Thanks. I had tried doing this a couple of times with "local $READER" which didn't work.

Comment: `$READER` is scalar. You need a glob. The key to using `>&READER` isn't `local`, it's the use of a glob.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `-C` option to `ls` to force it to use columnar output (without getting `IO::Pty` involved).

Comment: Thanks, but /bin/ls is just an easy example. I need a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [IO::Pty docs](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/IO-Tty-1.02/Pty.pm) describe a `clone_winsize_from(\*FH)` method. You might try cloning your actual pty's dimensions.

I see that you're setting up the `pty` only as `stdout` of the child process. You might need to set it up also as its `stdin` — when the child process sends the "query terminal size" escape sequence to its `stdout`, it would need to receive the response on its `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that and have tried it. Updated the code in my question to reflect the attempt.

Comment: Note that call *is* still required when eschewing open3 for fork/exec.

Comment: Updated answer with another suggestion.